# python requests raised SSLError, how to fix that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
print(s.get('https://imagetwist.com/')) # print(s.get('https://img119.imagetwist.com/'))
```

Error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='imagetwist.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

If I request a subdomain(https://img119.imagetwist.com/), it works fine.

Could someone help me, tks!

Python 3.6.9, ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: It looks like imagetwist.com and img119.imagetwist.com different configurations. The server serving imagetwist.com does not provide a valid certificate chain, which means Python can not resolve a safe validation.

Answer (score 3):

## Update

**I took the liberty to contact imagetwist.com and let them know of the problem. Within the hour they had fixed the issue with a complete certificate chain. Kudos to Imagetwist!**

--

### Redundant debug information for similar issues:

The server configuration of imagetwist.com is incorrect - it's not providing the full certificate chain back to a shared trusted CA. 
While Chrome (and others) will fill in the gaps, Python's library is unable to do so.

Compare the results from:

```
openssl s_client -connect img119.imagetwist.com:443 -showcerts
openssl s_client -connect imagetwist.com:443 -showcerts
```

Usually, the server will provide a list of certificates which will "synchronise" to a Certificate Authority certificate in your ca_bundle (A file/directory containing CAs recognised by you and your computer).

There are three options:

1. Ask imagetwist.com to fix their configuration (Good luck!)
2. Add their certificate to your ca_bundle (You'll have to renew everytime they update the cert)
3. Add the intermediates certs to your ca_bundle.

Option 3 is probably the best long term solution until imagetwist fix their setup.

Depending on your Python installation, you'll need to add the following to your ca_bundle, which will fill in missing cert chain on your machine:

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This intermediate certificate comes from the their correctly configured server (img119.imagetwist.com) instance.

I have then verified it using two methods:

1. Apple's Keychain: `openssl verify sectigo.crt`
2. Using Mozilla's converted cert chain: `curl https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem | openssl verify -CAfile /dev/stdin sectigo.crt`

Both result in:

```
sectigo.crt: OK
Chain:
depth=0: C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA (untrusted)
depth=1: C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
```

Therefore, the missing intermediate (Sectigo) certificate is validated by "The USERTRUST Network" CA present in the Apple default Keychain and Mozilla's CA Bundle.

Comment: how about if the `OP` want to scrape specific thing from the direct `url`, do you have valid solution ? you have advised him to not do this, but where the solution if he forced to scrape something from there?

Answer (score 1):

The error is explaining that is unable to verify the `SSL` certification by the `HOST`.

so you've to use `verify=False` for that case.

Check [SSL CERT Verification](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.5.3/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

And Here [Disable SSL Warnings](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings)

```py
import requests
import urllib3


urllib3.disable_warnings()

with requests.Session() as req:
    r = req.get("https://imagetwist.com/", verify=False)
    print(r)
```

Comment: This is bad advice unless someone really, really can not avoid it

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack i would like to see your answer for that question. what do you mean by `This is bad advice unless someone really`? if you are not the owner of the `host` which you are calling ! there's nothing to do with the `SSL Cert`, otherwise go ahead and go ask almost of site where the `cert` is unverified and then ask them to `verify` it.

Comment: I agree with @AlastairMcCormack when you get an ssl trust error the worst advice is just turn off the part thats trying to verify the host can be trusted. That an integral part of SSL is that the host has not been compromised or that your not being subjected to a man in the middle or DNS attack

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Well, we all agree that's unsafe to deal with `un-trusted` `cert`. but in the other side there's no way to be under `antibiotic` coverage. where i mean `Okay we know` but I've to deal with that site since i've task to be done. i just see the answer stating that you `don't do it` but where the solution itself for the `OP` or at least if you saying this is not good, offer for me a good solution

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη your comment doesnt make sense all your answer says is instead of trying to fix the error just ignore it. My point is then your essentially weakinging the whole point in using ssl in the first place. How do you know if the host can be trusted if you cannot validate them.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle well take it in `A-B-C` way. I'm not the owner of the `host`, but i would like to call it for extracting specific info, Now you are telling me it's bad to deal with un-trusted `SSL` cert, So i replying you back with `OK, tell me how to call it safely` ? which is the real logic for why the `maintainers` of `requests` package implement `verify=False` option and explained it in the docs. because there's no solution if you aren't the owner of the `host`

Comment: After a little investigation, the error is likely to caused by a newer cert being used on imagetwist.com that does not have a trust root on the OPs machine yet. Therefore, the resolution will be to update the ca_bundle on the OP's machine. That will be the likely solution - not to blindly switch off verification!

Comment: If the question was "I need to disable SSL verification in Python requests because the site uses an invalid certificate", then your answer would be sound.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack for a record,unless you know the trust root for the know host, then you can install it! which means we are repeating the circle. if i trust the host from the beginning

Comment: I am sorry but just because i cannot solve the OP problem doesnt mean you answer isnt bad. You cannot justify your answer by saying ok give a better answer. certificates are verified by taking the certificate and looking at the CA, if the CA is one from the trusted list of CA's then the certificate can be trusted. if its not then dont trust it. You broswers list of trusted CA's will be managed by your broswer provider and you can add to it your self. Chances are the CA. The CA who signed this cert is sectigo and likely hood is that this is not a trusted CA in the python installs default CAs

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη you can add the CA to your trusted root in python which will then enable chain root trust

Comment: @ChrisDoyle who said that my solution is not solving the issue for the `OP`, the final point is to get connected, and that's have been done. and for the point of  `CA`, you asking him to assign it for his trusted root. under which guarantee you assume it's safe?

Comment: As for the CA. Its easy to get a list of trusted and verified CA's you can even take it from your browser and verify it sha256 hash to make sure the CA you are going to install in your python env is the CA thats been verified by global oragnisations from a significant stringent verification process. that saves you having to worry or validate the CA

Comment: How does the OP know that whats being sent back by the "host" which they are not verifying to trust is not malicious data. I really cannot understand how you think the answer to fixing a security issue is turn off that part of the security. that would be like someone posting saying i cannot get to some site cause my firewall it blocking it and your solution being turn off your firewall

Comment: @ChrisDoyle there's a discussion been on [meta](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177728/is-it-safe-to-publish-a-private-cas-root-and-intermediate-certificates/177729) before. in case if you assume that `CA` is hundred percent protected. and in the other side, that's all based on the `GET` request where it's end with `Connection: 'closed'` which cut the connection once the `GET` request fully completed. Now if we do care about the content is being received, you aware that in both case the content can be `malicious` and it's based on your local environment protection itself

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη that meta article has nothing to do with this subject 

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack context is the target

Comment: What context? they are talking about creating their own CA and using it to sign certs they create. This question is about sectigo CA which is a public global CA. that CA has already been verified by browser company like google, Microsoft Firefox etc. So you dont need to do any of the trust validation on the CA cause huge companies have already done that and put it in their browser. So you can take the CA from your browser and store it in your python trusted CA list. you can even get the CA from chrome, firefox, edge and verify they all have the same sha256 fingerprint to give you confidence

Comment: If a trusted CA is compromised these large broswer companies are quick to react and remove it from the tursted CA list. Google about diginotar, a holland CA company which was compromised and how all the browser companies reacted to it